# Failed building wheel for Twisted in Windows 10 python 3

Tags: python, installation, pip, twisted

I'm trying to install rasa-core on my windows 10 machine.

When installing with pip install, I get: Failed building wheel for Twisted

The same error appears when trying to install Twisted separately.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Which python are u using?

Comment: @Nuts I'm using Python3

Comment: what version exactly of python 3? Also, can you provide the full pip install output? Not just the error but the whole output

Comment: Could you post the exact error-message?

Comment: It really doesn't matter which version of Python you're running, this is an ongoing issue in Windows. Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and download the required Twisted package. Also keep the the installer so you can use it on future projects because the packages are regularly updated and the previous versions aren't available on the site.

Answer (score 15):

Download the .whl file from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted)
then after you are in the virtualenv

`pip install C:\...yourpath...\Downlaods\<filename>`

e.g.

`pip install C:\...yourpath...\Downlaods\Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`

This worked for me..

Comment: Hey I am getting ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64 How can I resolve this? I already downloaded latest version

Comment: Make sure that you download the whl file that has the same `cp` number as your python version. I use python 3.8, so I downloaded this: `Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 4):

Download Twister package from [releases](https://twistedmatrix.com/Releases/Twisted/) and install it eg.

```
pip install C:\...yourpath...\Downlaods\Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 3):

## Install Twisted Using pip

Or Download [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) at this location
pip install Twisted-18.9.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 1):

No conda install or Microsoft Studio.

Follow:

1. Download Twisted : https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted
2. In CMD: `cd C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads`
3. `pip install Twisted-version.whl`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have Microsoft Visual C++ installed do so from the following link. Make sure you match the correct version for the Python you have installed.
https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2017_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29

Then install Twisted with: pip install Twisted[windows_platform]

Ensure you have [windows_platform] included.